# How can I change what cell is selected after I press Enter in Excel?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-excel-2010

Is there an Excel keyboard shortcut for changing editing , i.e., for "After pressing Enter, move Selection Direction (to) Right/Down"?

Answer (score 1):

Go to File --> Options --> Advanced and check "After pressing Enter, move
selection". Then choose the direction.

For more details, see http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/selection-after-enter-t4002870.html .